# Requests - GET depends on POST

Tags: python, post, cookies, get, python-requests

I'm trying to get some data from one Web Page. This web page uses `.Net`. According to firebug, when I click on a button, it sends two requests.

There are information in `POST` request. Then there is a `GET` request which gets the information I want to get.

I'm using `requests` module. I don't know how to make this two requests work together.

I've tried this:

```
r = requests.post("https://example.com/vyber.aspx",data=_params) # _params is a dictionary obtained from Firebug
r = requests.get("https://example.com/vyber.aspx")
print r.content
```

But it not works (it returns incorrect `HTML`) because those two requests are independent. I suppose that I have to store some kind of data (maybe cookies or whatever) to do `GET` request. But I don't know how.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I if i got you  need to use [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).
As the documentation says-

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance, and will use urllib3‘s connection pooling. So if
>   you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
>   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
>   performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies={'from-my': 'browser'})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add send headers to make it real

```
ses = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
}
r = ses.post("https://example.com/vyber.aspx",data=_params, headers=headers)
r = ses.get("https://example.com/vyber.aspx", headers=headers)
print r
```

you have to check that your params are like this {"name_in_html" : "value_you_want'}
also sometime websites wait to receive another parameter which has already a value like

```
<input type="TYPE" id="ID" name="NAME" value="SOMEVAL">
```

so you have to add {'NAME' : 'SOMEVAL'} to you data